# Converting a grid of strings into several rows of strings

Tags: java, arrays, string

**TL;DR Version**

Basically, a Java ASCII art thing that can output the contents of the grid of potential character points in the pattern in which they appear. If converted into Courier New or another font where all characters are the same width, the output should theoretically resemble the pattern which the user has created.

**Detailed Version**

I'm attempting to code a program that creates a grid of boxes; the area of the grid is user-specified, so the width and height are just that - ints called width and height. So far it's been smooth as anything, no problems at all.

The thing is, the boxes the grid consists of are instances of a CharPoint.class, each of which contains a one-letter string (I've named this string "contents" for lack of a better term) that is determined by the user's input while the CharPoint is selected. (If the contents string is null, the CharPoint shows up as an empty box in the color the user has selected for their foreground color.)

I want to iterate through each column in each successive row and add the value of that CharPoint's contents to an output string for an output function that will return the values of all of the points in the order in which they appear. Each row is one string, so if the user has ten rows and ten columns, there will be ten ten-character strings. Each null space is represented as an empty space string in the output (" ").

I'm having some difficulties actually arranging this. I tried going through a double for loop that goes through each column in each row like this:

```
for (int row = 0; row < this.height; row++)
{
    for (int column = 0; column < this.width; column++)
    {
        CharPoint cp = (CharPoint) charPoints.get(column + (row * 10));
        // other code here
    }
}
```

After determining which CharPoint it's looking at the function should take the CharPoint's contents and add it to the end of an initially length 0 output string (a new one for each row). After it's compiled the full row string, it should print it via System.out.println() (ignore the lack of proper user-accessible output for now). Unfortunately, I can't seem to find a good method of doing this, so I had to post this ridiculously specific question here.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you don't take offense but this does look something like a homework problem.  I'll answer your problem with solutions to two related problems which will hopefully help.

```
//Function to convert a list of characters to a String and print it
public void printCharactersAsString(List<Character> characters) {
  StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
  for(Character c : characters) {
    stringBuilder.append(c);
  }
  String finalString = stringBuilder.toString();
  System.out.println(finalString);
}

//Function to sum up each row and print the sum
public void printSums(List<Integer> grid, int width, int height) {
  for(int row = 0; row < height; row++) {
    int sum = 0;
    for(int col = 0; col < width; col++) {
      int number = grid.get(col + row*width);
      sum += number;
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
  }
}
```